# PHP Adding multidimensional arrays together

Tags: php, arrays, merge, append

I have been wondering how to add 2 multidimensional arrays together, I have found similar solutions but it is not exactly what I am trying to go for. Maybe one of you guys could help me out. Yes I know the title is almost the same as other asked questions, but trust me, I have looked for my answer but I can't find it.

```
# array1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product1 
            [1] => Description product 1          
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product2
            [1] => Description product 2       
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product3
            [1] => Description product 3       
        )
)

# array2
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price 1
            [1] => Something product 1        
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price 2
            [1] => Something product 2    
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price 3
            [1] => Something product 3      
        )
)

#resultant array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product1 
            [1] => Description product 1
            [3] => Price 1
            [4] => Something product 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product2
            [1] => Description product 2
            [2] => Price 2
            [3] => Something product 2      
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product3
            [1] => Description product 3  
            [2] => Price 3
            [3] => Something product 3   
        )
)
```

As you can see I would like to add the 2 arrays together. I have seen several other answers but they use the build in php function `array_merge()`. If I use that it will result in something like this:

```
#resultant array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product1 
            [1] => Description product 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product2
            [1] => Description product 2     
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product3
            [1] => Description product 3   
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price 1
            [1] => Something product 1        
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price 2
            [1] => Something product 2    
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price 3
            [1] => Something product 3      
        )
)
)
```

As you can see that is not what I am looking for unfortunately. I am hoping to find a solution for my problem.

Thanks for reading my post.

Cheers Cody

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `array_merge` to each of your subarrays using `array_map`:

```
$result = array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2);
```

For more information check the manual for [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), especially example 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
$final = [];
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
// loop over the second array elements
 foreach($arr2[$key] as $key2 => $value2){
 // append the second array values to the first array
   $value[] = $value2;
 }
// append the new array to the final array
$final[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work, but array_map worked better since it is a build in function of PHP and way less code to write, thanks again for your answer.